# Native UIEvent() not cleared after event end

Tags: javascript

I have a click listener:

`document.getElementById("addData").addEventListener("click", addData);`

If before actually clicking i take a memory snapshot and look for UIEvent inside Objects, it's not existing. But after clicking , if i take another snapshot and go trough the allocated objects, i can see UIEvent and MouseEvent (native js interfaces) .

The question is, why are those objects kept in memory? if i didn't need them before the actual event, why would i need them after the end of the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click somewhere, the browser internally calls `new MouseEvent("click");`, the same way you would programatically create a "virtual click" on a page. This code will do the same thing, as you clicking on the page but it's done explicitly :

```
var evt=new MouseEvent('click');
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

`MouseEvent` inherits from `UIEvent` so both constructors are called:

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
 console.log("evt instanceof MouseEvent :",evt instanceof MouseEvent);
 console.log("evt instanceof UIEvent :",evt instanceof UIEvent);
});
```

The event will get garbage collected if there is no reference to it after a while. You can get more informations about memory management and garbage collection in javascript on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i know listeners kept in memory. The question was why the specific UIEvent and MouseEvent not appearing before the actual event happening if they are kept in memory after the event finished.

Comment: I'm not talking about the listener, but the event object itself. evt here is an instance of Mouse Event AND UIEvent, in my code I keep the event in memory as there is a reference to it on the `window` object.

Comment: when you click somewhere you're listening on "click" event (not sure if you need to listen though) the browser internally calls `new MouseEvent("click");`